# Ubuntu: Play audio file using SoX play command

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, audio, startup

*Edited:*

I'm trying to play a sound on my Ubuntu through SSH using SoX `play` command.
When I boot my machine and after I physically access the machine and log into the Ubuntu GUI, I can run this `play` command and play my file and hear the audio output from machine. This works regardless of whether I run the command from a local session or through SSH session. This still works even when I lock the GUI.

But on reboot, and before I log into my Ubuntu GUI, when I SSH into it and run `play` I cannot hear any sound but every other command works fine, including installing and removing packages, runnings openvpn service, `scp` files between the machine and a client. Also, even though no audio output could be heard, SSH terminal shows no error; SoX show me the audio is playing.

*Note: I have not enabled complete root user access to my server through SSH. I can still `sudo` things fine but I cannot `scp` anything directly from `/root`, for example.*

My guess is that my audio service or module is not activated before GUI login. Any clues on this?

**Machine: MacBook Air 2017**

**Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.1 LTS**

Comment: Do you any error when you use  `play` command and this one doesn't work?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon, thanks for asking this, I do not get any error and SSH terminal shows that the audio is playing. I edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution for this. I figured there was a group called audio that only had pulse user listed. I had to add the user I was using to access SSH (user_name) to the audio group.

1. Find what users are added to the audio group

```
$ less /etc/group | grep audio
>>> audio:x:29:pulse
```

2. Let’s double check the name of current user:

```
$ who
>>> user_name      pts/0        2023-01-18 08:55 (10.0.0.167
```

3. Make sure your user belongs to this group. The output from step 1 shows that pulse is currently set as the only user of audio. So let’s add user_name to this group.

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G audio user_name
```

4. Double checking to see if it worked

```
$ less /etc/group | grep audio
>>> audio:x:29:pulse,user_name
```

5. Give it a reboot and vola!

```
$ sudo reboot
After reboot and re-login
$ play audio_file.mp3
```